# Code for subtraction on first calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

First and foremost, hello I am new to this site and I am also quite new and still learning. I have been working on a calculator as a small beginner project. I am having some issues getting down the subtraction portion. I will post my full work and maybe some ideas can arise. Thanks! //I am using Brackets if anybody just wants to know

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm">

<input name="result">
</br>
<input type="button" name="1" value="1" onClick="run1()">
<input type="button" name="1" value="2" onClick="run2()">
<input type="button" name="1" value="3" onClick="run3()">
<input type="button" name="1" value="4" onClick="run4()">
<input type="button" name="1" value="5" onClick="run5()">
<input type="button" name="1" value="6" onClick="run6()">
<input type="button" name="1" value="7" onClick="run7()">
<input type="button" name="1" value="8" onClick="run8()">
<input type="button" name="1" value="9" onClick="run9()">
<input type="button" name="plus" value="+" onClick="runplus()">
</br>
<input type="button" name="calc" value="=" onClick="evalu()">
</form>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

function run1()
{document.frm.result.value += "1";}
function run2()
{document.frm.result.value += "2";}
function run3()
{document.frm.result.value += "3";}
function run4()
{document.frm.result.value += "4";}
function run5()
{document.frm.result.value += "5";}
function run6()
{document.frm.result.value += "6";}
function run7()
{document.frm.result.value += "7";}
function run8()
{document.frm.result.value += "8";}
function run9()
{document.frm.result.value += "9";}
function runplus()
{document.frm.result.value += "+";}

function evalu(){

 var evalo = eval(document.frm.result.value)

 document.frm.result.value = evalo;

}


</script>
</body>
</html>﻿
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually the **optimal** or efficient way to build a calculator; however since you're brand new we can push that aside for now. Welcome to JavaScript! :D

You should be able to create a minus button just exactly like you've created your plus button.

`<input type="button" value="-" onClick="runminus()">`

Javascript:

```
function runminus() {
    document.frm.result.value += "-";
}
```